# How do I train my dataset on Tesseract library?

Tags: tesseract, tess4j

I have a datasets with a lot of gt.txt and tiff files about 1000 files, I tried to use the tesstrain project and run the follow command make **training MODEL_NAME=cmc7 TESSDATA=path/to/tessdata_best** This command run with success but when I try to use the traineddata It doesn't work as expected. My question is what is the right form to training my datasets for tesseract? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To train my dataset with images I use 2 types of files in adition to the images:

- the **gt.txt** files with the expected output
- **box files** generated out of the images with the changes I want to train the model with

I place all 3 files inside *tesstrain/data/my-model-ground-truth* and run the following command from the tesstrain folder:

```
make training MODEL_NAME=my-model START_MODEL=eng TESSDATA=../tessdata_best
```

That is supposing you want to train on top of the *eng.traineddata* from the *tessdata_best* repository:
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best

That generates my-model.traineddata inside the *tesstrain/data* folder

Comment: How could I generate box files?? Is there some software to do that?

Comment: Box files can be generated using Tesseract 4.0 using the lstmbox config from image data using tesseract <image name including extension> <box file name> lstmbox.
Edit: Source https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/TrainingTesseract-4.00.html